# Inspecting vector linear dependence, one line in matrix all zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have vectors $v1, v2,v3$ and we want to inspect their linear dependence.
They are linearly dependent when the only solution for the equation $\alpha * v1 + \beta * v2 + \gamma * v3 = 0$ is $\alpha = 0, \beta = 0, \gamma = 0 $.
We want to inspect if they are linearly dependent so we multiply trough coordinates and we get:

$(\alpha * X_{1},\alpha * Y_{1}, \alpha * Z_{1}) + (\beta * X_{2},\beta * Y_{2}, \beta * Z_{2}) + (\gamma * X_{3},\gamma * Y_{3}, \gamma * Z_{3}) = (0. 0, 0)$

Substituting this into a matrix and solving by Gaussian elimination shows that one row is lets say $M_{3,n}$ is all zeroes i.e. ${M_{3,1} = 0, M_{3,2} = 0, M_{3,3} = 0}$.
In my text book they say this is a sign that vectors $v1, v2, v3$ are linearly dependent and my **question** **is why?** By eliminating the thirds row we only eliminated the $Z$ coordinate, not a whole vector... Can anyone clarify this a bit for me?

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter, whether you have zero row or zero column. If you have matrix $n \times n$, where rows are vectors and columns are their coordinates, then zero row means that you may, for example, add some row to this row and using a property that rank (maximum number of independent vectors) of $(v_1, ..., v_n)$ equals rank of $(v_1, ..., v_n+v_j)$, you will have two equal rows ($j$ and $n$), so vectors realted to these lines are linearly dependent. In case you have a zero column, you can say that some coordinate variable is missing in your matrix. Thus, all your vectors are in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. If you have a set of vectors with number of elements more than space dimension, then these vectors are definitely linearly dependent (as we can have at most $\dim V$ linearly independent vectors in space $V$).

Comment: just one more: what is the best way to formulate the conclusion that they are LD for example when writing on a paper, when one column zeroes out?

Comment: You may either find $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_N$ in $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + \dots a_nv_n$ explicitly and, thus, present one of $v_i$ as linear combination of the other, or mention a property that maximum size of set of linearly independent vectors in space $V$ = $\dim V$. As in case of zeroing one column, all vectors are included in space $V', \dim V' = \dim V - 1$, they can't form linearly independent set.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got this correctly.
To my understanding, the book essentially says you transform the system of equations  into a vector equation of the form
$$Mv=0,$$
where (by applying Gaussian elimination) you have that $M$ has a row of zeros. Then the book concludes by saying that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly dependent.

If this is the case, the book's conclusion holds since $M$ has a row of zeros, hence $det(M)=0$ (Gaussian elimination involves elementary operations which do not alter the invertibility of the matrix), which implies the existence of a non-zero solution $v$ such that $Mv=0$.